# How to check that a String has a specific prefix in a #Predicate macro?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm surprised to see that `#Predicate` doesn't support the basic `hasPrefix(_:)` function by turning it into the equivalent of `BEGINSWITH` in the old `NSPredicate`.

```
let predicate = #Predicate<String> { $0.hasPrefix("some prefix") }
```

> The `hasPrefix(_:)` function is not supported in this predicate (from
> macro 'Predicate')

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate), `Predicate` supports the `Sequence` method `starts(with:)`, but not `hasPrefix`, which is a `StringProtocol` method.

> In the predicate’s definition, you can use the following operations:
>
> - ...
> - Sequence operations (`allSatisfy()`, `filter()`, `contains()`, `contains(where:)`, `starts(with:)`)

So you should do

```
let predicate = #Predicate<String> { $0.starts(with: "some prefix") }
```

Comment: This code fails to compile : The starts(with:) function is not supported in this predicate (from macro 'Predicate').

Comment: @parapote The latest Xcode beta is beta 3, released just 2 days ago. Are you using that version? Can you call the [`PredicateExpressions.build_starts(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicateexpressions/4227245-build_starts) method with some `PredicateExpressions.Value` arguments? The macro expansion should contain a call to that.

Comment: Indeed, it now works with Xcode 15 beta 3. Thanks a lot!